# webサーバーからスマホアプリの操作

Tags: ios, android, node.js

ぷらぷら検索していましたら、モバイル向けのフリマアプリ（メルカリ）にweb上から出品できるサービスを見つけました（メルポンというやつです）。メルカリはスマホアプリのみから出品可能で、web上からは出品できません。このサービスはどういった仕組みでスマホアプリを操作しているのでしょうか。
それ用のツールなどがあるのでしょうか。

Comment: 単純にSSL Proxy(Charlesとかね)をカマしてhttpsの通信をスニッフしただけでしょう。そしたらAPIのリクエスト・レスポンスは丸見えです。携帯アプリの開発者な‌​ら誰でもやっています。プロキシが発行する偽のルート認証局の証明書をあえてインストールして、そこから発行されているSSL証明書を使えば、携帯はプロキシを本物の接続先と見なすようになります。これで通信内容が筒抜けになるわけです。

Answer (score 4, accepted):

プログラムからアプリを操作する方法は、AndroidのuiautomatorやiOSのInstrumentなど、開発者向けに提供されているものがあります。これを使いやすくラップしたAppiumなどのツールもあります。

[スマホ向け無料システムテスト自動化ツール（8）：SeleniumのUIテスト自動化をiOS／AndroidにもたらすAppiumの基礎知識とインストール方法、基本的な使い方 (1/4) - ＠IT](http://www.atmarkit.co.jp/ait/articles/1504/27/news025.html)

ただこの場合、同時処理が必要な数だけ端末を用意する必要がありますし、サービスとして提供するには向かないように思います。（本来の目的である、アプリの自動テストなどは実機でやることに意味があるので仕方ありませんが）

ですから、「アプリを操作している」のではなく「アプリに成りすましてサーバーと通信している」のではないでしょうか。単純なHTTP(S)通信であればFiddlerやCharlesなどのプロキシサーバーで、そうでなければパケットキャプチャをするなどして通信を解析することができます。